# SBT unable to find installed java on my machine despite $JAVA_HOME set correctly

Tags: scala, sbt

I did

```
brew install scala
brew install sbt
```

scala works fine for me, however when I try to run sbt, I get:

```
⇒  sbt
grep: warning: GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated; please use an alias or script

No java installations was detected.
Please go to http://www.java.com/getjava/ and download


siddhartha@Siddharthas-MacBook-Pro-2:~|
⇒  echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I checked the following 2 links but neither have a helpful answer:

[No Java installation was detected while sbt update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862252/no-java-installation-was-detected-while-sbt-update)

[Why does sbt report "No java installations was detected" with $JAVA_HOME set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657610/why-does-sbt-report-no-java-installations-was-detected-with-java-home-set)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you set `PATH` variable besides `JAVA_HOME`? Does `java -version` work for you?

Comment: Yes ```java version``` works fine. I did a ```printenv``` and I don't see any other PATH variables that may prove to be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to do a `sudo`. I suppose permissions for sbt in /usr/local are set for root when installed via brew.

Answer (score 0):

The sbt script that launches java ([sbt-launch-lib.bash](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/blob/6935bee2c7b6123f93ad4e96db11acf315671929/src/universal/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash#L276)) prints “No java installations was detected” (now “No Java Development Kit (JDK) installation was detected.”) if there is any error running `java -version` with the current environment variables `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`, `_JAVA_OPTIONS`. So if either of these variables contains impossible options, sbt will give the misleading error instead of the actual error.

`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` or `_JAVA_OPTIONS` might be misconfigured to have a too large memory usage (e.g. `-Xms100g`). Or it might be misconfigured to listen to a debug port (e.g. `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_sockerver=y,suspend=n,address=5005`) that is already bound by another program.

The sbt script applies `JAVA_OPTS` and `SBT_OPTS` only after checking `java -version`, so if you set those instead, then you may get a better error message.