# Sbt can't find Java

Tags: java, scala, parsing, path, sbt

When I try to launch sbt, I get the following message:

```
~(501)$sbt
(standard_in) 1: parse error

No java installations was detected.
Please go to http://www.java.com/getjava/ and download
```

However, both Java and Scala are installed

```
~(508)$java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

And this is Scala

```
~(503)$scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 9.0.1).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala>
```

And you can find them in the path

Java path

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/"     
export PATH=$PATH:"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/"
```

Sbt path

```
export SBT_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/sbt/1.0.3/bin/" 
export PATH=$PATH:$SBT_HOME
```

and Scala path

```
export SCALA_HOME="/usr/local/opt/scala/idea"
export PATH=$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin
```

I'm running all these in a Mac Os Sierra v10.12.6
I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` shouldn't point to the same directory.
`JAVA_HOME` points to Java directory and `PATH` to its `bin` subdirectory.
For example for me

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
$ echo $PATH
...:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:...
```

See also

[Why does sbt report "No java installations was detected" with $JAVA_HOME set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657610/why-does-sbt-report-no-java-installations-was-detected-with-java-home-set)

[No Java installation was detected while sbt update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862252/no-java-installation-was-detected-while-sbt-update)

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163418/no-java-installations-was-detected-although-i-have-java

[Installing Java on OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533528/installing-java-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks)

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answer, It helped me a lot.

Most important was a fix on the grep options:

```
   #GREP_OPTIONS="--color=always";export GREP_OPTIONS
   #pay attention - don't use previous line or sbt for scala won't work,
   #this is the reason why to keep active the following line
   GREP_OPTIONS=""
```

In addition, I rewrite properly paths and variable settings. In the way I set a fresh install of sbt from zip file, so I included a specific alias to override previous settings and launch it in .bash_profile

```
### Java 
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home"
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

### SBT
#alias is to force launch from fresh install from .zip file
alias sbt="~/sbt/bin/sbt"
export SBT_HOME="~/sbt"
export PATH=$PATH:$SBT_HOME/bin
```